# Stripe Connect - How to transfer money from multiple account to one destination

Tags: stripe-payments

I know how to transfer money from one account to another one but I need recommendation regarding the following scheme

Need to send 100$ to destination customer
90$ from client
10$ from platform

Is it possible?

Comment: Hi b3lowster, I think what you are after is Stripe's Separate Charges & Transfers flow, which is documented here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers. The idea is that you would create a payment intent for $90, then create a separate transfer from your platform to the connected account for $100. The key is that the platform will assume the Stripe fees, so the platform will net ~$87 from the client, but will still transfer the full $100 to the destination account.

Comment: @ttmarek
client sends 90$ to platform and platform sends to customer 100$. is it correct?

Comment: it depends a bit on your definitions. But yes, the cardholders would pay the platform $90 and the platform would then send $100 to the connected account.

Comment: @ttmarek Sorry I've forgotten to leave feedback. I've got your idea. Thanks

Comment: @ttmarek
I've got the following error `An Exception has been thrown: When creating or updating a PaymentIntent, you cannot provide a transfer_data[amount] that exceeds the PaymentIntent's amount.` :(

Comment: by the sounds of it you are attempting to create the transfer using a destination charge which would throw that error. You need to create a separate transfer (apart from the payment intent) as shown in the first example on this page here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers